# How to fade in dynamic <li> elements one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function for displaying my data on the page which loops over an array. I am stuck trying to display the li elements one at a time, the current code displays the elements as one block.

```
function displayData() { 
const allLi = document.querySelector('article > ul');
allLi.innerHTML = '';

 pageSnippits.forEach(function(page) {
     const searchUlOut = document.querySelector('article > ul');
     const searchLiOut = document.createElement('li');
     searchLiOut.innerHTML = '<h3>' + page.title + '</h3>' + '<p>' + page.extract + '</p>';
     searchUlOut.appendChild(searchLiOut);
     setTimeout(function() {
         searchLiOut.classList.add('animated', 'fadeInUp');
     }, 10);
});
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are setting them to all come in 10 seconds after you go through the loop. I would suggest maybe adding a count variable that you increment in your loop, and then:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    searchLiOut.classList.add('animated', 'fadeInUp');
}, 10000 * count);
```

or something like that.

Comment: Besides the fact that 10 in setTimeout does NOT wait for 10 seconds (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) , this will not solve the OP's problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `setInterval` takes time in milliseconds. 10 milliseconds is too short for a visual effect to be normally visible.

Basically the issue is when you loop through your array using forEach, each time the code encounters a `setInterval`, it sets the timer and continues code execution. The loop finishes before even the first timer fires and all the set timers fire at the same time. There are a lot of links discussing how Javascript timers work. See [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/) for example.

My solution would be to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`. I have created a code snippet to give you some ideas. See if it helps solving your problem.

```js
function displayData() { 

var pageSnippits =['javascript','is','da','best'];


var index=0;
var handle = setInterval(function() {
        var searchUlOut = document.querySelector('article > ul');
        var searchLiOut = document.createElement('li');
        
         searchLiOut.innerHTML = '<h3>' + pageSnippits[index] + '</h3>' + '<p>' + pageSnippits[index] + '</p>';
         searchLiOut.classList.add('w3-animate-opacity');
         searchUlOut.appendChild(searchLiOut);
         
         index++;
         if(index>=pageSnippits.length) clearInterval(handle);
     }, 1000);
}

displayData()
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<article>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html)!
download wow.js and animated.css

Comment: How does this helps the OP?

Comment: add js css your projects add li tag wow js attribute that work